# How to change test result path of Concordion?

Tags: concordion

How can I set the test result path for Concordion? I'm using Java for Concordion and HTML as the markup language for the spec file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the system property `concordion.output.dir` to the target output path.

Comment: I've raised an issue on this, since it's not well documented. The website currently only mentions it in the Maven and Gradle sections of the Integrations page.

Comment: Just wanted to elaborate further:

`System.setProperty('concordion.output.dir', 'directory_of_output')`

Thanks!